# Compare two columns of strings for row-wise text match

Tags: r, text, match

In a single dataset (QueryTM), I have two columns Query and TM. I want to check if the Query contains value of TM (in the same row) or not. Consider an example, If TM is "Coca Cola" and Query is "Coca Cola India", Query should match with TM. However, if query is "Coca Colala India", it shouldn't match. The results are to be stored in another column, say Result

I am using R as the platform.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add word boundaries to capture exact matching. Using `mapply` you can do,

```
dd$result <- mapply(grepl, paste0('\\b', dd$TM, '\\b'), dd$Query)

dd
#            TM              Query result
#1    Coca Cola  Coca Colala India  FALSE
#2 Fanta Orange Fanta Orange India   TRUE
```

**DATA**

```
dput(dd)
structure(list(TM = c("Coca Cola", "Fanta Orange"), Query = c("Coca Colala India", 
"Fanta Orange India")), .Names = c("TM", "Query"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```